# htmlunit, null в page.getElementById()

Tags: java, htmlunit

Есть `htmlunit` парсер, который парсит сайт, на котором контент загружается аяксом, пример кода:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://site.name");
```

`div` с айдишником `overview` загружается через аякс, при вызове `page.asXml()` - нужный `div` есть внутри `page`, при вызове `page.getElementById("overview")` выскакивает ошибка `NullPointerException`. Как сделать чтобы через `getElementById()` был доступен нужный `div`?

Comment: Что такое URL ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос текст исключения вместе с трассой стека, и адрес сайта (если не секрет).

Comment: @zRrr в printStackTrace() просто: java.lang.NullPointerException at parser.Main.main(Main.java:80), сайт на локалхосте

Answer (score 1):

Исходных данных маловато, но всё же, если кусок

```
page.getElementById("overview")
```

выделен в отдельную строчку и на нём падает **NullPointerException**, то значит, что твоя переменная **page** равна **null** . Попробуй после строчки

```
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://site.name");
```

сделать старый добрый сисоут:

```
System.out.println((page == null ? "Error: page is null":"normal"));
```

и если в консоли до падения исключения появится

```
Error: page is null
```

то проблема не в самом html, а в его получении.